# Regex for label=value

Tags: php, regex

I need to build a single regex to match this 2 kinds of line:

> 1)SBNID=304,MENAME=RV0714,MEID=122,CELLID=4,CELLNAME=LRV0714D
>
> 2)MBTS_ACN1_RJ/ETHPORT:Cabinet No.=0, Subrack No.=0, Slot No.=7, Port
>   No.=0, Subboard Type=BASE_BOARD

The output must be: For the first (1):

> SBNID , MENAME , MEID , CELLID , CELLNAME

For the second (2):

> Cabinet No. , Subrack No , Slot No. , Port No , Subboard Type

**PS: Since my code process each input by time, I need to process first the input one, then input 2, not both together**

I already tried:

```
(?<![^:,])[^=]+
```

Works for the second case, but for the first case it not returns SBNID

I am using pcre(php) regex

Comment: You don't need the values like `304` or `7`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you're looking for key/value pairs. This could be achieved via

```
(?P<key>\b[A-Za-z\h.]+)=(?P<value>\w+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/v6jUrY/2/).

---

Broken down this says:

```
(?P<key>\b[A-Za-z\h.]+) # capture A-Z, a-z or horizontal whitespaces 
                        # into group "key"
=                       # = literally
(?P<value>\w+)          # capture A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _ 
                        # into group "value"
```

---

Glued together in `PHP` this would be:

```
<?php

$string = "SBNID=304,MENAME=RV0714,MEID=122,CELLID=4,CELLNAME=LRV0714D
MBTS_ACN1_RJ/ETHPORT:Cabinet No.=0, Subrack No.=0, Slot No.=7, Port No.=0, Subboard Type=BASE_BOARD";

$regex = '~(?P<key>\b[A-Za-z\h.]+)=(?P<value>\w+)~';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    print_r($match);
}

?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/kxMBd3).

Answer (score 1):

This works for both of your examples:

```
preg_match_all('/([\w\s.]+)=/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

If there are other characters that you would want to allow then just add them inside the character class `[]`.

You might want to trim any captured spaces:

```
$result = array_map('trim', $matches[1]);
```